# Visual Studio 2010 C++ Unexpected Command Line Args

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

Please tell me how I can input:

```
2 3 4 + *
```

into the VS 2010 command line. 
I'm working on a Reverse Polish Notation program. Input expects `char *argv`.
Whenever I put `2 3 4 + *` into the VS 2010/Project/Debugging/Cmd Line Args, I use `printf("%s", argv)` to get,

> D5x --> where x is some garbage character.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 3):

`argv` is an array of pointers to strings.  Trying to print it with `printf("%s", argv)` will never give you anything useful, because `%s` tells `printf` to expect a string.

Try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("[%d] - %s\n", i, argv[i]);
}
```

Comment: I get this exception when using my command line args, and your code. Unhandled exception at 0x548913af (msvcr100d.dll) in ReversePolishNotation.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000044.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<argc;++i){
        printf("%s ", argv[i]);
    }
}

>prog 2 3 4 + *
2 3 4 + *
```